# which design patten in this situation?

Tags: spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC and need to provide ability to change fields of some object separately. For example in controller I have method for every field (new value is assigned in service method) but I'm wondering if there is good design pattern to use in this situation. I mean to have in controller only one method for all fields. I thought about sending new value of field and name and then check which field should be changed in controller but in this situation I get many if statements... Is there any widely used method in this situation?

```
class Controller {

@RequestMapping(value = "/field", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String changeFieldValue(@RequestParam("fieldname") String fieldName, @RequestParam("newValue") String newValue, ModelMap model){


    if(fieldname.equals("age")){
        Object.setAge(newValue);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
}
```

I think about sth similar to this, I know that I can populate whole object at once. but requirements are to change fields separately

Comment: Could you provide some example code of your scenario and how you're trying to solve it?

Comment: I think about sending ajax post with field name and new value and next to check in controller the field name and invoke suitable method on Object but this will require many if statements (checking based on posted fieldname), so I  thought there is maybe common pattern to perform such things?

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a BeanWrapper implementation to ease this task.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapperImpl.html

```
BeanWrapper wrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(object);
wrapper.setPropertyValue(fieldName, newValue);
```